# Pass method name as string and assign to delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I seem to be going no-where fast with passing a method name as a string and assigning it to a delegate.

I want to have a class that assigns a dynamic method from a parameter but can't work out how to do it.

```
    private delegate void ProgressMsg(string msg);
    private ProgressMsg AddMsg;

    public Progress(string FormName, string AddMsgMethodName, bool close, bool hide)
    {
        // set properties
        this.Hide = hide;
        this.Close = close;

        // Open form if not open
        this.Frm = Application.OpenForms[FormName];
        if (this.Frm == null)
        {
            // instatiate form
            this.Frm = (Form)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + FormName);

            // show form
            this.Frm.Show();
        }

        // assign delegate
        this.AddMsg = new ProgressMsg(AddMsgMethodName);

        // Hide form
        this.Frm.Visible = !Hide;


    }
```

How can I pass the name of a form, and the method to call and then assign to the delegate the method from the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
this.AddMsg = (ProgressMsg)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ProgressMsg), this.Frm, AddMsgMethodName);
```

Comment: Great thanks. Always like it when the code can be reduced like that :-)

That first line was a little difficult to read for me anyhow!

Answer (score 2):

In .Net 4.5 you can use the CallerMemberNameAttribute to get the name of the calling method.  I use this all the time with INotifyPropertyChanged.  This way I can write this:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return this._name; }
    set
    {
        if (this._name != value)
        {
            this._name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(); //no argument passed
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute]string propertyName = "")
{ //propertyName will be set to "Name"
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

[See here for more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection. The following code assumes that the method in question always takes exactly one parameter of type `string`.

```
var method = this.Frm.GetType().GetMethod(AddMsgMethodName,
      new Type[] { typeof(string) });

this.AddMsg = (ProgressMsg)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ProgressMsg), this.Frm, method);
```

Comment: I'm getting a casting (or lack of) error?

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Delegate' to 'Progress.ProgressMsg'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I explicitly cast it and it seems to be OK.

this.AddMsg = (ProgressMsg) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ProgressMsg), method);

Comment: Thanks, that was doing my head in. I'm very fuzzy when it comes to delegates, If I have to hard code the method to call, why am I not simply calling it? - I'm missing some point for sure, and just hope it comes with time.

Comment: You don't need the first line as you can simply provide the method name instead of the `MethodInfo` as a parameter for `CreateDelegate`. See my answer. You won't have to specify parameter types for the delegate as well then.

Comment: @RobertS.: Nice catch, +1 from me. I'll leave my answer here, since it's more robust with respect to multiple overloads.